# How to get my own facebook updates to show in my website?

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to get my last posts from facebook to store on a database or an array.
I tried to get my own updates by doing this:

```
<?

    require_once("src/facebook.php");

    $config = array();
    $config['appId'] = 'appId';
    $config['secret'] = 'secretId';
    $config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

    $facebook = new Facebook($config);

    $feed = $facebook->api('/myUserId/feed');

    print_r($feed);

?>
```

But it returned only my personal information, not my updates, something like that:

```
Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => ################## [from] => Array ( [name] => My Name [id] => My Id ) [story] => My Name likes a photo. [story_tags] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => myId [name] => My Name [offset] => 0 [length] => 13 [type] => user ) ) ) [type] => status [application] => Array ( [name] => Likes [id] => ######## ) [created_time] => 2012-09-27T13:31:52+0000 [updated_time] => 2012-09-27T13:31:52+0000 [comments] => Array ( [count] => 0 ) ) ) [paging] => Array ( [previous] => https://graph.facebook.com/#######/feed?limit=25&since=1348752712&__previous=1 [next] => https://graph.facebook.com/#########/feed?limit=25&until=1348752711 ) )
```

What am i missing??

Comment: You can use the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to get your bearings within their API. It's a great tool to learn about all the relations between objects.

Comment: I couldn't get exactly what I want by the documentation. I could only get info from the user loged in the session. I need to show my updates regardless user log in or confirmation.

Comment: You need to take a look at the lifetime of access tokens. you must have a valid token to access a users information. You might not be able to get all the information you seek.